# How to update one object variable on a SQL database?

Tags: java, mysql

I have it set up where I can save my object information to a SQL database using this block of code:

```
public boolean add(PizzaOrder aOrder) {
    boolean success = false;
    PreparedStatement statement;
StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();
int rowCount;

    if (aOrder != null && dbConnect != null && dbConnect.isConnected()) {
        try {
            sqlStr.append("INSERT INTO ");
            sqlStr.append(ORDER_TABLE);
            sqlStr.append(" (firstName, lastName, size, cheese, sausage, ham, total)");
            sqlStr.append(" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            statement = dbConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlStr.toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
           statement.setString(1, aOrder.getFirstName());
           statement.setString(2, aOrder.getLastName());
           statement.setString(3, aOrder.getPizzaSize());
           statement.setBoolean(4, aOrder.getCheese());
           statement.setBoolean(5, aOrder.getSausage());
           statement.setBoolean(6, aOrder.getHam());
           statement.setDouble(7, aOrder.getTotal());

            rowCount = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rowCount == 1) {
                ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
                if(rs.next()) {
                    aOrder.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                }
                success = true;
            }
        }
        catch  (SQLException e) {
            String prompt = e.getMessage() 
                        + " cannot save pizza order information for " 
                        + aOrder.getFullName();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, prompt, "SQL Server Error: Insert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    else if (aOrder == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Pizza Order object is null");
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Database is not connected");

    }
    return success;
}
```

What I am trying to do is change the total variable with an update to the object on the server. I dont have an error right now popping up but nothing is changing in my objects information. Here is my code with the update block:

```
public boolean update(PizzaOrder aOrder)  {
    boolean success = false;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();
int rowCount;

    if(aOrder != null && dbConnect != null && dbConnect.isConnected()) {
        try {
            //TODO create the SQL and prepared statements to update an order in the database
            rowCount = aOrder.getId();
            sqlStr.append("UPDATE ");
            sqlStr.append("pizzaorder ");
            sqlStr.append("SET firstName = ?, lastName = ?, size = ?, cheese = ?, sausage = ?, ham = ?, total = ? WHERE id = ").append(rowCount);

            statement = dbConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlStr.toString());
            statement.setString(1, aOrder.getFirstName());
            statement.setString(2, aOrder.getLastName());
            statement.setString(3, aOrder.getPizzaSize());
            statement.setBoolean(4, aOrder.getCheese());
            statement.setBoolean(5, aOrder.getSausage());
            statement.setBoolean(6, aOrder.getHam());
            statement.setDouble(7, aOrder.getTotal());

            rowCount = statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch  (SQLException e) {
            String prompt = e.getMessage() 
                            + " cannot update pizza order information for " 
                            + aOrder.getFullName();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, prompt, "SQL Server Error: Update", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    else if (aOrder == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Pizza Order object is null");
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Database is not connected");

    }
    return success;
}
```

I have it set up that just the total variable will be changed by the time the update block of code will be ran. So I was trying to just call all the variables again in the hopes that it would change the total.

I get the same results with this update block of code:

```
public boolean update(PizzaOrder aOrder)  {
    boolean success = false;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();
int rowCount;

    if(aOrder != null && dbConnect != null && dbConnect.isConnected()) {
        try {
            rowCount = aOrder.getId();
            sqlStr.append("UPDATE ");
            sqlStr.append("pizzaorder ");
            sqlStr.append("SET total = ? WHERE id = ").append(rowCount);

            statement = dbConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlStr.toString());
            statement.setDouble(1, aOrder.getTotal());

            rowCount = statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch  (SQLException e) {
            String prompt = e.getMessage() 
                            + " cannot update pizza order information for " 
                            + aOrder.getFullName();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, prompt, "SQL Server Error: Update", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    else if (aOrder == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Pizza Order object is null");
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Database is not connected");

    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use prepared statements for all the variables, but for the `WHERE id=...` condition use simple string concatenation with `append(rowCount)`? And what is the result of `rowCount` after you have executed the query?

Comment: You can set `profileSQL=true` in your connection url to indicate what statements have been sent to MySQL server by MySQL JDBC Driver. Maybe the information will be helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: Progman you are right I had it messed up I got it working and posted an answer down below. I had an issue elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem I had something elsewhere in my code blocking the update. This is the code that is working to update the mySQL database in this case:

```
try {
            //TODO create the SQL and prepared statements to update an order in the database
            sqlStr.append("UPDATE ");
            sqlStr.append("pizzaorder ");
            sqlStr.append("SET total = ? WHERE id = ?");

            statement = dbConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlStr.toString());
            statement.setDouble(1, aOrder.getTotal());
            statement.setInt(2, aOrder.getId());

            rowCount = statement.executeUpdate();
        }
```